# Initialize an array (string or any other data type) inside a Struct

Tags: c#, arrays, string, struct, dynamic-arrays

I'm looking to do this in C#.

```
public struct Structure1
{ string string1 ;            //Can be set dynamically
  public string[] stringArr; //Needs to be set dynamically
}
```

In general, how should one initialize an array dynamically if need be?
In simplest of terms, I'm trying to achieve this in C#:

```
  int[] array;  
  for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
        array[i] = i;
```

Another example:

```
  string[] array1;  
      for (int i=0; i < DynamicValue; i++) 
            array1[i] = "SomeValue";
```

Comment: How do you mean *dynamically*? You don't want to pass those values to the constructor?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the struct part comes in. Why do you have a mutable struct in the first place?

Comment: Do you want to set int values to your string array?

Comment: By dynamically, I mean that the size of the array is unknown. So using int[] array = new int[10] or specifying 10 anywhere is not helpful.the array should get values at a later point in the code and it's size should also be determined at that time. Is it possible to utilize another data type in this case?

Comment: I want to use an array/string array etc. to be initialized later (not at declaration) to be used inside a struct

Comment: @Magnus, I do not need to set int values in the string array, it was just an example .

Comment: The stringArr variable will be of what ever size array you assign it.

Comment: @Amy: Why are you using a struct

Comment: why not use a List<string> and Add as many elements as you need, when you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your code will almost work:

```
int[] array = new int[10]; // This is the only line that needs changing  
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
    array[i] = i;
```

You could potentially initialize your arrays within your struct by adding a custom constructor, and then initialize it calling the constructor when you create the struct.  This would be required with a class.

That being said, I'd strongly recommend using a class here and not a struct.  Mutable structs are a bad idea - and structs containing reference types are also a very bad idea.

---

Edit:

If you're trying to make a collection where the length is dynamic, you can use `List<T>` instead of an array:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
    list.Add(i);

// To show usage...
Console.WriteLine("List has {0} elements.  4th == {1}", list.Count, list[3]);
```

Comment: thanks, what if I do not know the size of the array is 10 and it should be determined dynamically?

Comment: @Amy: Then you should consider using `List<T>` instead of an array.

Comment: I would need to pass this information into a Javascript call, which is why I was thinking in terms of an array or string to keep it simple. Any other ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
```

**update**

```
int x=10;
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// IF you are going to use a struct
public struct Structure1
{
    readonly string String1;
    readonly string[] stringArr;
    readonly List<string> myList;

    public Structure1(string String1)
    {
        // all fields must be initialized or assigned in the 
        // constructor


        // readonly members can only be initialized or assigned
        // in the constructor
        this.String1 = String1

        // initialize stringArr - this will also make the array 
        // a fixed length array as it cannot be changed; however
        // the contents of each element can be changed
        stringArr = new string[] {};

        // if you use a List<string> instead of array, you can 
        // initialize myList and add items to it via a public setter
        myList = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> StructList
    {
        // you can alter the contents and size of the list
        get { return myList;}
    }
}
```